# Country name with zend locale

Tags: php, zend-framework, internationalization, zend-locale

When I save countries into my database I use the international abbreviation.

How do I convert this abbreviation with `zend_locale` to the full country name?

Comment: you can do that bu using extra table that map between both : http://27.org/isocountrylist/iso_country_list.sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the method. It tries to use the browser's locale and defaults to US English if that fails.

```
try {
    $locale = new Zend_Locale(Zend_Locale::BROWSER);
    $countries = $locale->getTranslationList('Territory', Zend_Locale::BROWSER, 2);
} catch (exception $e) {
    $locale = new Zend_Locale('en_US');
    $countries = $locale->getTranslationList('Territory', 'en_US', 2);
}

asort($countries, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);

// Unset invalid countries
// SU = USSR
// ZZ = Unknown or Invalid Region
// VD = North Vietnam
// DD = East Germany
unset($countries['SU'], $countries['ZZ'], $countries['VD'], $countries['DD']);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use functionality from the `intl` extension which is bundled as of PHP 5.3.0, or as a PECL extension as of PHP 5.2.0.

To display a region using a locale:

```
<?php
print \Locale::getDisplayRegion('da_DK') . "\n";
print \Locale::getDisplayRegion('en_US') . "\n";
print \Locale::getDisplayRegion('ru_RU', 'ru_RU') . "\n";
?>
```

Will output:

```
Denmark
United States
Россия
```

http://php.net/manual/en/locale.getdisplayregion.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `Zend_Locale::getTranslationList()` or `Zend_Locale::getTranslation()`. See [example #7 in the manual](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.locale.functions.html#zend.locale.getdata).